# How to use other table field in SQL Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I have a scenario were i need to select the rows from one table provided the the condition satisfies in other table.

Sorry if i am confusing....

I am using MySQL as database with python 2.6 to connect to DB.

i have table employee with empid,availability
other table works with shot,empid,availability

i need to retrieve all the shots from `works` where empid availability of `works` is same as in employee table

i have posted my [SQL here @ fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b621/13)

i need my result to be like below

> shot  empid   availability
>
> 002   P4645   Online
>
> 003   P6682   Online
>
> 005   P4645   Online
>
> 006   P6682   Online
>
> 009   P4645   Online
>
> 010   P6682   Online

Since all records are online in works table. but empid 1863 is offline in employee table so records other than this empid should be retrieved. I cannot hard-code this as this SQL as

```
select x.shot,x.empid,x.availability from work x
inner join (
  select empid,availability from employee where empid = 'P4645') y on y.availability = x.availability
where x.empid <> '1863'
```

as it will be generated dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
select * 
  from work x join employee e
    on e.availability = x.availability
   and e.empid = x.empid
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b621/17)**